# No theft model of corruption

Tags: economics

Consider the model of corruption explored by Shleifer and Vishni’s where there is one
government-produced good $X$. There is a demand for that good described by the inverse
demand equation
$$Q_d = 10 – P.$$
The official government price for the good is $P_g=3$. The government pays the cost of producing the good. A bureaucrat can restrict the supply of $X$. Since there is no risk of detection, the public official has incentives to ask for a bribe to supply the good.

Consider the model of “no theft” where the consumer pays the official government price
plus a bribe in order to obtain $X$. Assume that the official marginal revenue for selling the
good in this context is given by $$Q_c=\frac{7-P}{2}.$$

a) In the model of “no theft” what is the amount of the bribe that the corrupt official will
charge?

Comment: +1, first time i am seeing an attempt to mathematically model bribery. Awesome!

Comment: Home work tag? Explain what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The official wants to maximize his income, so will set the price so the marginal income is zero.  The bribe is the excess of the price over $3$.

Comment: Does this make the answer 2?

Comment: I think I'm working it out wrong, I got 7-3/2?

Comment: In my first answer I assumed the official got everything over $3$. Watch for an update

Comment: Qc=(7/2)-(1/2)P or (7/2)-(3/2), so Qc must be 2 as 3.5-1.5=2, the total payed by the comsumer is 5, 3 being the set price and 2 being the bribe. Is this right?

Comment: $P$ is the selling price including the bribe, so it is not fixed at $3$

Comment: Can you explain what i am doing wrong so i can understand?

Comment: The question is whether $Q_c$ is marginal revenue per unit or total.  If $Q_c$ is marginal revenue for all the units, you want to set it to zero, as with a lower price the official can increase his take by charging more and with a higher one he can increase his take by charging less.  Then we get $P=7$.

Comment: If $Q_c$ is marginal revenue per unit, for a $1$ unit increase in price he loses $\frac 12$ per unit but gains $1$ unit in sales.  I am reading it total, but am not sure.